# Camera always look at target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am quite new to Unity. I am trying to make a simple script that makes the camera always look at the ship in the scene.

I have:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LookAt : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform playerShip;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.LookAt(playerShip);
    }
}
```

I have named the target in the scene playerShip but it gives me an error:

```
Assets/LookAtShip.cs(7,9): error CS0118: `UnityEngine.Component.gameObject' is a `property' but a `type' was expected
```

Comment: Missing semicolon after `public GameObject playerShip` for starters...

Comment: Again the error message is (almost) self-explanatory: class `GameObject` exists in the `UnityEngine.Component` namespace, which you haven't directly imported.

Comment: @imperium be aware that `GameObject` (the class) exists in `UnityEngine` but `gameObject` is a property of the script. Edited

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I got it working, I'll update my question.

Comment: Please share `LookAtShip.cs`, as that is where the error is located. You seem to have shared `LookAt.cs` instead.

Comment: Just looking at the error code, you probably used `gameObject` instead of `GameObject` in a property definition. It's impossible to be sure unless you share the relevant code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I renamed LookAtShip.cs to just LookAt.cs as it made more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You must use: transform.LookAt(playerShip.position);

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LookAt : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform playerShip;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.LookAt(playerShip.position);
    }
}
```